# Query Deleted Subscriber in All Subscriber List In MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, subscriber

Is there a way to query MC to identify if a subscriber was deleted from the All subscriber list at any point in time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a few methods you can you use to assist, but I'm afraid that Marketing Cloud doesn't keep very good logs when it comes to activity in the system and I don't think you'll find that data on your own. You may be able to request that from Marketing Cloud Support, but I believe that would require a services engagement and would incur a charge.